# Which Toolbox has Gjlim function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a system of equations by the Gauss-Jordan method, the book uses the Gjelim function but I cannot find the Toolbox that implements it. I would appreciate if anyone has this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't referenced exactly the book you're looking at, but as noted in [Linear Algebra with Applications (Gareth Williams, p.532)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1xXTvSfL4DYC&pg=PA532&lpg=PA532&dq=Gjelim+matlab&source=bl&ots=rfpGk7_mls&sig=ACfU3U02lPMknFQIsPQ6XNSW6ROSMhcwMw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik6NWaz8byAhURoVwKHXUEB-AQ6AF6BAgSEAM#v=onepage&q=Gjelim%20matlab&f=false)

> MATLAB contains functions for working with matrices. New functions can also be written in the MATLAB language. **The function `gjelim` has been written for Gauss-Jordan elimination**. It includes a "rational number" option (the default mode is decimal number), a "count of arithmetic operations" option, and an "all steps" option that displays all the steps. **`gjelim` and other MATLAB programs are found in The Linear Algebra with Applications Toolbox available from [http://www.stetson.edu/~gwilliam/mfiles.htm](http://www.stetson.edu/%7Egwilliam/mfiles.htm)**

Unfortunately this link appears to now be dead, but it is still available on archive.org (here is the most recent entry from Sept 2019):

[https://web.archive.org/web/20180214124023/http://www2.stetson.edu/~gwilliam/mfiles.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20180214124023/http://www2.stetson.edu/%7Egwilliam/mfiles.htm)

And the link for downloading the toolbox zip is still served by that archive:

[https://web.archive.org/web/20180214124023/http://www2.stetson.edu/~gwilliam/mfiles.ZIP](https://web.archive.org/web/20180214124023/http://www2.stetson.edu/%7Egwilliam/mfiles.ZIP)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate the time you took to place the links!!